I have byhearted the poem
I know that I have learnt the poem by heart is idiomatic and correct native English. But most Indians, even the teachers of English use byheart as a verb. One of the English professors who I worked with also said that byheart could be used as a verb.
I would like to solicit your kind opinion on this usage. Do you consider it faulty Indianism or acceptable as a neologism?

I don't like "byheart" as a verb, meaning "memorize".  Neolism?

This question has an answer on ELL . James K says it should be considered "incorrect" when speaking British or American English.

It's not in most of the common online dictionaries (Cambridge, American Heritage, Merriam-Webster, Longman), which indicates many readers will find it odd, and may judge it an error.
As the answers for this question about using neologisms on the Writing StackExchange point out, it's best to consider your audience and the effect you're aiming for with your writing.
It's not faulty as new words are created all the time, but it definitely could be an unacceptable neologism depending on the context and purpose of its use.

It is listed by Cambridge but not in American English dictionaries  such as M-W and AHDEL, the term (verb) is hyphenated in CD and in Wiktionary. I think "nonstandard" is a more appropriate expression than "faulty".

@Mari-Lou A 'Nonstandard' is not appropriate in 'It's not Ø as new words are created all the time'.

@EdwinA How do you read that sentence? I can't understand it, since it looks like 'It's not empty set as new words are created all the time'.

@Conrado The Ø symbol stands for a word to be inserted (here, 'faulty' in the original, 'nonstandard' if we consider this substitution). It's (among other things) the empty string symbol (Wikipedia), here used as a placeholder with two possible candidates (underscoring seems more of an invitation to add any word/s).


Do you consider it a faulty Indianism

In Indian English it is entirely acceptable - nothing "faulty" about it. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/byheart

or acceptable as a neologism?

It isn't a neologism in Indian English as it is accepted and has been for some time.
It isn't a neologism in American or British English as it is not used.
